# Override Property in Subclass from Baseclass Interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

i got a problem with overwriting a property which comes from an Interface. I got one Base Class which implements an Interface. This class has arround 10 Subclasses. The subclasses should overwrite the property which comes from the Interface in some cases.

My problem is, that i access the property while not knowing what type of class the object has and the object allways returns the  base class property value instead of the overwritten subclass property value.

Example Code simplified:

```
public interface Inf
{
   string Info
   {
     get;      
   }
}


public class BaseClass : Inf
{

   public string Info
   {
      get { return "Something"; }
   }

}


public class SubClass : BaseClass 
{

   new public string Info
   {
      get { return "Something else"; }
   }

}
```

in another class i have to access the property, i dont know if the object is type of base or subclass at this moment

```
List<BaseClass> listBase = new List<BaseClass>();
listBase.Add(new BaseClass());
listBase.Add(new SubClass());

foreach (BaseClass obj in listBase)
{
  Console.WriteLine(obj.Info);
}
```

Output:

```
Something
Something
```

wanted output:

```
Something
Something else
```

((SubClass)obj).Info  would output "Something else"
but at this certain moment i dont know what kind of class the object is. (i have arround 10 different subclasses).

Do i have to cast all objects to it's real class? i got like 100-200 objects in this list and arround 10 different classes. Or is there any other way to do this?

any help appreciated :)

Comment: Would overriding/virtual method solve your issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should make the property implementation `virtual` in the base class, and put `override` instead of `new` on the implementations in derived classes. This should fix the problem.

Currently, the only class that provides the implementation for the property `Info` from the interface `Inf` is your `BaseClass`. According to your code, compiler thinks that the derived class `SubClass` introduces a new property with the same name, which is legal. Such property would be accessible only when you use the class directly, not through an interface.

Answer (score 8):

You have broken the chain by "new"ing the property. You need to override it:

```
public interface Inf
{
   string Info
   {
     get;      
   }
}

public class BaseClass : Inf
{
   public virtual string Info
   {
      get { return "Something"; }
   }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass 
{    
   public override string Info
   {
      get { return "Something else"; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're doing it wrong. Do following:

- declare base class property using `virtual` keyword
- add `override` keyword next to subclass property declaration

```
public class BaseClass : Inf
{
    public virtual string Info
    {
        get { return "Something"; }
    }
}


public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string Info
    {
        get { return "Something else"; }
    }
}
```

With that the result is as you expect.

Read more about overriding and polymorphism here: [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)